# Verificar se dia existe no mês

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Preciso de verificar/validar se um dia (numérico) existe num determinado mês.

Por exemplo: tenho o dia `31`, e como não existe no mês de Fevereiro a condição irá falhar.

Penso que um simples `if` me resolverá o problema, onde construo uma data e verifica se a mesma existe.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Voce pode descobrir qual o último dia do mês 'x':

```
public bool IsDiaValido(int dia, int mes, int ano)
{
    int ultimoDiaMes = DateTime.DaysInMonth(ano, mes);
    if(dia > ultimoDiaMes || dia < 1)
        return false;
    else
       return true;
}
```

Dessa forma você não precisar colocar um try-catch, evitando gerar um erro desnecessariamente.

Comment: retorna `true` para IsDiaValido(-1, 12, 2014);

Comment: Alterei o código, obrgiado @AndréFigueiredo

Comment: Eu sei que algumas pessoas não gostam, mas é tão mais fácil fazer: `return dia >= 1 && dia <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(ano, mes)`.

Comment: Também prefiro, só deixei desta forma para ficar mais claro. Detesto fazer if-else para retornar um boleano.

Comment: Não que eu seja contra deixar claro o código, mas na prática muita gente copia como está, e acaba "consagrando" esse tipo de código. Eu acho que é mais interessante fazer a forma "técnica", e explicar no texto o que está acontecendo (mas é apenas a minha humilde opinião). De qq forma, o +1 está dado.

Answer (score 4):

Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas do jeito que faço é:

```
try
{
    var test = Convert.ToDateTime("31/02/2014");
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    // Não existe a data
}
```

Comment: Se performance estiver em jogo, a captura de uma exceção dessa forma pode ser custosa. Fora isso, funciona, então +1.

Answer (score 4):

Um simples [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) já diz se a data proposta em `string` é uma data válida já levando em conta os dias diferentes de cada mês e anos bissextos:

```
public bool isValidDate(string value) {
    DateTime result;
    return DateTime.TryParse(value, out result);
}
```

Sobrecarga:

```
public bool isValidDate(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
    try {
        return DateTime.Parse(dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano) > DateTime.MinValue;
    } catch { }
    return false;
}
```

E outras variantes...

É necessário um try/catch para casos anômalos, como dia = `0` ou dia `32`, o que é possível ou qualquer exceção que venha a acontecer.
No caso do TryParse não é necessário porque o try/catch já está embutido na função.

**Testes executados com sucesso:**

```
c.isValidDate(null);        // false
c.isValidDate("");          // false
c.isValidDate("       ");       // false

c.isValidDate("31/01/2014");    // true
c.isValidDate("28/02/2014");    // true
c.isValidDate("29/02/2012");    // true
c.isValidDate("29/02/2014");    // false
c.isValidDate("-29/02/2014");   // false
c.isValidDate("29/0/2014");     // false

c.isValidDate(31, 01, 2014);    // true
c.isValidDate(28, 02, 2014);    // true
c.isValidDate(29, 02, 2012);    // true
c.isValidDate(29, 02, 2014);    // false

c.isValidDate(-1, 02, 2014);    // false
c.isValidDate(31, 01, -1);      // false
c.isValidDate(15, 0, 2014);     // false
c.isValidDate(99, 99, 9999);    // false
c.isValidDate(01, 01, 0001);    // true
```

Answer (score 4):

Resolvi responder para não consagrar uma forma redundante de código. Também estou dando opção de *overload* para uma *string* com a data.

```
public bool EhDiaValido(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
    return dia >= DateTime.MinValue && dia <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(ano, mes);
}

public bool EhDiaValido(string data) {
    DateTime resultado;
    return DateTime.TryParse(data, out resultado);
}
```

No C# 7 o último método pode ser escrito como:

```
public bool EhDiaValido(string data) {
    return DateTime.TryParse(data, out var resultado);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/ValidDayInMonth.cs)

Answer (score 1):

Simples, tente criar a data e veja se falha:

```
DateTime dia;
try {
  dia = new DateTime(year: 2014, month: 02, day: 31);
} catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) {
  // A data não existe, tratar
}
```

Funçãozinha simples:

```
static bool DataExiste(int ano, int mes, int dia) {
  try {
    new DateTime(ano, mes, dia);
    return true;
  } catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { }

  return false;
}
```